# How can I send an attribute to my directive with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this HTML for my ckEditor:

```
<textarea data-ck-editor="text" data-ng-model="modal.data.text"></textarea>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var ck = null;
            var config = attr.editorSize;
            var abc = attr.abc
            var def = attr.def
            if (config == 'wide') {
                ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], { customConfig: 'config-wide.js' });
            } else {
                ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], { customConfig: 'config-narrow.js' });
            }
```

From my HTML, how can I send a value for editorSize, abc and def ? Could I send this as part of the

```
data-ck-editor="text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done the main part just add the attributes like

```
<textarea data-ck-editor="text" data-ng-model="modal.data.text" editorSize="something" abc="something" def="something"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is this valid for all the browsers? The reason I am asking is my VS2013 IDE reports these as unknown attributes. Also could I pass it as part of the "data-ck-editor="text" "  for example data-ck-editor="something, something, something" ?

Comment: these are valid for all browsers. The reason VS2013 is saying so is that the html is not well formed. But for angular code it will work everywhere

Comment: Thanks. Did you see my other question. Could I pass this as part of the "text" that I specify in data-ck-editor ?

Comment: there is no need to do that @Melina. This is the angular way of doing it.